All ways to arrange 3 letters from A,B,C,D,E and 3 numbers from 0-9 in a string so that no letter appears twice and the first character is a letter
As the title suggests, I am trying to answer
"Find all ways to arrange 3 letters from A,B,C,D,E and 3 numbers from 0-9 in a string so that":

No letter appears twice
The first character is a letter

My solution attempt:

Choose the first position to be a letter which can be done in $5$ ways (since there are $5$ possible letters)

Then choose the $2$ remaining characters to be placed out: $\binom 4 2$

Finally choose $3$ numbers. They can be choosed in any way so we have $10^3$ options for numbers.


Now permute 1-2 (everything except the first letter) which can be done in $5!$ ways since we have $(6-1)=5!$ positions to freely choose the remaining letters.
We get
$$5\cdot \binom 4 2 \cdot 10^3\cdot 5!$$
options.
The answer key instead does:

Pick 3 positions for the digits and pick 3 digits: $\binom 5 3\cdot 10^3$
Then choose the letters: $5\cdot 4 \cdot 3$.

I am undercounting in my solution, but why is that so?

In the first step of the answer key, it looks like the author is selecting three positions for the numbers (not letters) and then selecting three numbers (not letters) to fill those positions.

Correct, I re-read the sheet and realized my mistake. I will update the question right away to be correct.

First, you are overcounting, as:
$5\cdot \binom 4 2 \cdot 10^3\cdot 5! = \binom 5 3\cdot 10^3 \cdot 5!\cdot 3 $ which is more than the provided answer.
Now why is that?
It is because of the last step, you shouldn't permute everything.
For example, for the case where you choose 9 9 9 as your numbers, permutating them would get you the same thing so you would be counting it many times.
You don't need to permute the numbers too, because in the way you counted how many numbers you can choose, for example $a_1a_2a_3$, you assured that you would get $a_3a_2a_1$, $a_2a_3a_1$, etc., which are all permutations of $a_1a_2a_3$.
The fact that you can repeatedly choose a number will garantee you that you will get the other cases/permutations.
In other words, you counted the permutations of the numbers in the $10^3$ term, so you don't need to permutate them again, so you would only need to add $5 \cdot 4$ instead of $5!$ which would get you the right answer.

I see, however I don't follow why I should add $5\cdot 4$ instead of $5!$. I would argue it is $2!$ I should add instead.
Choose the first letter: $5$ ways
Choose remaining letters: $\binom 4 2$
Permute remaining letters: $2$ letters can be ordered in $2!$ ways.
Choose digits: can be done in $10^3$ ways

My line of thinking was, you got 5 spots lefts, and you need to put 2 different letters in those five spots, leaving the rest for the numbers which don't need permuting. So the first letter would have 5 places, and the second would have 4 places, hence $5 \cdot 4$ . Keep in mind you are permuting the places of the 2 letters and not the letters themselves, hence if you permute 2 of 5 elements, you get $\frac{5!}{3!} = 5 \cdot 4$

I see, thank you!
